# Evaluate $\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\cos m\theta-\cos m \phi}{\cos \theta - \cos \phi} \text{d}\theta$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

In the Hardy's book *Divergent series* is proved the equality
$$\frac{\cos m\theta-\cos m \phi}{\cos \theta - \cos \phi} \text{d}\theta=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n\phi}{\sin \phi} \cos n\theta(\cos m\theta-\cos m \phi)$$
With $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Then integrating that equality $0<\theta<\pi$ (he says "ignoring any difficulties about the range of $\theta$ over which it may be expected to be valid) we obtain
$$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\cos m\theta-\cos m \phi}{\cos \theta - \cos \phi} \text{d}\theta=\pi \frac{\sin m\phi}{\sin \phi}$$
How that result is reached? I've tried, in a sloppy way (because I didn't proved the possibility to exchange series and integral), this approach with Werner identities
$$\int_0^\pi 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n\phi}{\sin \phi} \cos n\theta(\cos m\theta-\cos m \phi) \text{d}\theta=$$
$$2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n\phi}{\sin \phi} \int_0^\pi (\cos n\theta \cos m\theta-\cos n\theta\cos m \phi) \text{d}\theta=$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n\phi}{\sin \phi} \int_0^\pi (\cos (n\theta+m\theta)+\cos (n\theta-m\theta) -\cos (n\theta+m\phi) -\cos (n\theta-m\phi)) \text{d}\theta=$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n\phi}{\sin \phi} \left[\frac{\sin (n\theta+m\theta)}{n+m}+\frac{\sin(n\theta-m\theta)}{n-m} -\frac{\sin(n\theta+m\phi)}{n} -\frac{\sin(n\theta-m\phi)}{n}\right]_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi}=$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n\phi}{\sin \phi} \left[\frac{\sin (n\pi+m\pi)}{n+m}+\frac{\sin(n\pi-m\pi)}{n-m} -\frac{\sin(n\pi+m\phi)}{n} -\frac{\sin(n\pi-m\phi)}{n}\right]$$
And here I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Using approach0.xyz research tool, I found this proof by induction by "vanstraelen" : https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h627103p3762369

Comment: See as well https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3061827/compute-int-0-pi-frac-cosnx-cosx-cosnt-cost-cosx-cost

Answer (score 5):

Here is my approach to the problem. It is natural to think of complex analysis. Let $\sqrt{-1}=i$. Now we will prove that:
$$I_m:=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\cos mx}{\cos x - \cos \phi}\mathrm{d}x = \pi\cdot \frac{\sin m\phi}{\sin \phi}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\cos mx}{\cos x - \cos \phi}\mathrm{d}x$$$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{e^{imx}+e^{-imx}}{\left(e^{ix}-e^{i\phi}\right)\left(e^{ix}-e^{-i\phi}\right)}\mathrm{d}x$$

Let $z=e^{ix}$, $\mathrm{d}z = ie^{ix}\mathrm{d}x$. Hence:
$$I_m = \frac{-1}{4\sin\phi}\left(\int_{\vert z\vert=1}\frac{z^m}{\left(z-e^{i\phi}\right)\left(z-e^{-i\phi}\right)}\mathrm{d}z-\int_{\vert z\vert=1}\frac{z^{-m}}{\left(z-e^{i\phi}\right)\left(z-e^{i\phi}\right)}\mathrm{d}z\right)=A_m-B_m$$
Where:
$$A_m:=\frac{-1}{4\sin\phi}\int_{\vert z\vert=1}\frac{z^m}{\left(z-e^{i\phi}\right)\left(z-e^{-i\phi}\right)}\mathrm{d}z$$
$$B_m:=\frac{-1}{4\sin\phi}\int_{\vert z\vert=1}\frac{z^{-m}}{\left(z-e^{i\phi}\right)\left(z-e^{-i\phi}\right)}\mathrm{d}z$$

We need to show that $B_m = 0, \forall m \in \mathbb{N}$.It is obvious for $n=1$ We only need to show that:
$$J_m:=\int_{\vert z \vert = 1} \frac{1}{z^m (z-z_1)}\mathrm{d}z = 0, \forall m\in \mathbb{N}, z_1 = e^{i\phi}. $$
By induction, it is obvious that for $m=1$, we have $J_1= 0$. Assume that $J_m =0$ for $m=n-1$. We need to show that $J_n =0$.Since $\frac{1}{z^m}, m>1$ is a meromorphic function, by partial fraction decomposition:
$$J_n=z_1^{-1}\int_{\vert z \vert = 1}\frac{1}{z^{n}} - \frac{1}{z^{n-1}(z-z_1)}\mathrm{d}z=0 - J_{n-1}=0.$$
By obtaining this result, it follows directly that $B_m=0$.Finally, for $A_m$ by Residue theorem, leads us:
$$I_m:=A_m=\frac{-2\pi i}{4\sin\phi}\left(e^{im\phi}-e^{-im\phi}\right)=\pi \frac{\sin m\phi}{\sin \phi}$$
Then your result follows easily since:
$$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\cos m\theta-\cos m \phi}{\cos \theta - \cos \phi} \text{d}\theta=I_m - I_0 =\pi \frac{\sin m\phi}{\sin \phi}$$

Comment: This can be turned into a workable method, but $I_m$ diverges for real $\phi$. If $\phi \not \in \mathbb R$ or $I_m, A_m, B_m, J_m$ are understood as p.v. integrals (although neither is the simplest way), then $A_m = B_m$ and $J_m \neq 0$. Also, there should be an $e^{ix}$ factor in the second line, and the third line should be $I_m = 2 i (A_m + B_m) \sin \phi$.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that perhaps my answer isn't exactly what this post is looking for but I thought you would all appreciate seeing the question being done using techniques taught at high school.

We will need to make use of the following result...
$$
\text{(1)}\hspace{1cm}\frac{\sin nz}{\sin z}=e^{i(n-1)z}+e^{i(n-3)z}+\ldots+e^{-i(n-1)z}
$$
We can show this by using Euler's formula to express the sine function.
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin nz}{\sin z}&=\frac{\frac{e^{inz}-e^{-inz}}{2i}}{\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}}\\
&=\frac{e^{inz}-e^{-inz}}{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}\\
&=e^{i(n-1)z}+e^{i(n-3)z}+\ldots+e^{-i(n-1)z}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n e^{i(n+1-2k)\theta}\\
&=\sum_{l=1}^n e^{i(2l-(n+1))\theta}
\end{align*}
$$
Begin by using the sum to product identities and employing (1)...
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos n\theta-\cos n\phi}{\cos \theta-\cos\phi}\,\mathrm{d}\theta&=\int_0^\pi\frac{-2\sin\left(n\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}\right)\sin\left(n\frac{\theta-\phi}{2}\right)}{-2\sin\left(\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\theta-\phi}{2}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin\left(n\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}\right)}\times\frac{\sin\left(n\frac{\theta-\phi}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\theta-\phi}{2}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&\stackrel{\text{(1)}}{=}\int_0^\pi\left(\sum_{k=1}^n e^{i(n+1-2k)\frac{\theta+\phi}2}\right)\left(\sum_{l=1}^n e^{i(2l-(n+1))\frac{\theta-\phi}2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^n\int_0^\pi e^{i[(l-k)\theta+(n+1-k-l)\phi]}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=e^{i(n+1)\phi}\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^ne^{-i(k+l)\phi}\int_0^\pi e^{i(l-k)\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=e^{i(n+1)\phi}\left(\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{l=1}^{k-1}e^{-i(k+l)\phi}\int_0^\pi e^{i(l-k)\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta+\sum_{l=2}^n\sum_{k=1}^{l-1}e^{-i(k+l)\phi}\int_0^\pi e^{i(l-k)\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta+\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=k}^ke^{-i(k+l)\phi}\int_0^\pi e^{i(l-k)\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\right)\\
&=e^{i(n+1)\phi}\left(\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{l=1}^{k-1}e^{-i(k+l)\phi}\int_0^\pi e^{i(l-k)\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta+\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{l=1}^{k-1}e^{-i(k+l)\phi}\int_0^\pi e^{-i(l-k)\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta+\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=k}^ke^{-i(k+l)\phi}\int_0^\pi e^{i(l-k)\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\right)\\
&=e^{i(n+1)\phi}\left(\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{l=1}^{k-1}e^{-i(k+l)\phi}\int_0^\pi e^{i(l-k)\theta}+e^{-i(l-k)\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta+\sum_{k=1}^ne^{-i(k+k)\phi}\int_0^\pi e^{i(k-k)\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\right)\\
&=e^{i(n+1)\phi}\left(\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{l=1}^{k-1}e^{-i(k+l)\phi}\int_0^\pi 2\cos\left((l-k)\theta\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta+\sum_{k=1}^ne^{-i(k+k)\phi}\int_0^\pi\,\mathrm{d}\theta\right)\\
&=e^{i(n+1)\phi}\left(\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{l=1}^{k-1}e^{-i(k+l)\phi}\left[\frac2{l-k}\sin\left((l-k)\theta\right)\right]_0^\pi+\pi\sum_{k=1}^ne^{-i2k\phi}\right)\\
&=\pi e^{i(n+1)\phi}\sum_{k=1}^ne^{-i2k\phi}=\pi \sum_{k=1}^ne^{n+1-i2k\phi}\\
&\stackrel{\text{(1)}}{=}\pi\frac{\sin n\phi}{\sin\phi}
\end{align*}
$$